# Relation between group of completion and field of fractions

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, k-theory

I recently learned group completion in K-theory. I feel it is very similar to field of fractions of integral domain. Recall the definitions:

Group completion:
For an abelian monoid $M$, we define its group completion $M^{-1} M$ as free abelian group, each element $[m]$ satisfying $m \in M$. The group completion needs to quotient subgroup generated by $[m+n] - [m] - [n]$.

Field of fractions:
For an integral domain $M$, we define its field of fractions $M^{-1} M$ as product $M \times M^*$ quotient equivalence relation $(a, b) \sim (c, d) $ if $ad = bc$.

I think field of fractions is just group completion of multiplicative structure of a ring. Is it correct?

Comment: No, because the group completion of $(M-\{0\}, \times)$ does not carry the additive structure with it.

Comment: They are both, however, left adjoints to forgetful functors, so there are some similarities.

Comment: @Randall, I think if we ignore the additive structure in the integral domain. Then these two definitions should be the same. It means the forget functor could induce a commutative diagram between group of completion and field of fractions.

Comment: I think this is what you really mean to ask.  Let $G(M)$ be the group completion of a monoid $M$.  Let $\mathbb{F}(D)$ be the field of fractions of an integral domain $D$.  Finally, let $R^\times$ be the group of units of a ring $R$ with identity.  Then is it true that $(\mathbb{F}(D))^\times \cong G(D-\{0\})$ for every integral domain $D$ (with the iso natural)?

Comment: @Randall Yes, thank you, professor!